# Duplicating an oracle database on a computer not connected to the same network

Tags: database, oracle, backup

I need to duplicate an entire database to a computer (wich also runs oracle server) wich is on a different network than my oracle (production) server. For security reasons the 2 networks cannot communicate with each other. The database contains more or less 100 tables.

I am a developer and I have never done any serious administration on a database before so I don't really know where to start to be honest.
I thought about creating a script copying everything in an XLS file and than from the XLS file, recreate a complete DB but I have BLOBS in the DB so it is impossible. I also don't want to change my script every time a new table is added.

I don't know how to do that properly and most article I see on this topic are about RMAN so this solution won't work either.

EDIT1 : the Data Pump Export solution won't work unfortunately :(. I don't have admin privileges so I cannot point to a folder on my computer to export the dmp files.

Thanks in advance for you time.

Comment: I am new to stackoverflow and this is the second question I ask.  If I don't know why you downvoted it I won't be able to improve so I would appreciate to know why you downvoted it.

Comment: "New"? Your profile says "Member for 1 year, 9 months". Anyway: I presume that person - who thinks that this should be closed because it "doesn’t meet a Stack Overflow guideline" (probably because we're mostly discussing programming problems here) - also pushed the "downvote" button. I don't expect them to respond, I've very rarely seen someone explaining the reason.

Comment: yes I know but when I say new I mean I didn't ask much questions eventhough I created my account almost 2 years ago ;) . Thanks for your answer though Littlefoot, I appreciate

Answer (score 2):

It looks as if you'd like to move one **schema**, not the entire database.

If so, I suggest you use Data Pump Export (in the source database) to export the whole schema, and Import (in the target database) to import everything you previously exported.

Depending on your database version, maybe a simpler *original* EXP/IMP utilities would do the job correctly.

I certainly wouldn't want to do it table-by-table via CSV files; that's close to *suicide*.

Comment: I upvoted your answer but as my reputation is below 15 it is not displaying :(. Thanks a lot for your answer, I will look it up on the internet ;)

Comment: @cuveliernicolas I upvoted it on your behalf.

Comment: @cuveliernicolas Also be sure that your method (I vote for datapump, too) is approved by the appropriate security or Information Assurance folks. I don't know your exact situation, but moving data between air-gapped networks can often have legal implications and not merely technical ones.

Comment: @pmdba Yes I will ask my N+1 for this but it's complicated in terms of security here